# Is any matrix a sum of a scalar matrix and traceless matrix in the case of nonzero characteristic of the underlying field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over the field $F$. If the characteristic of $F$ is $0$, then $$A=\left(A-\dfrac{1}{n}\mathrm{trace}(A)\mathrm{I}_n\right)+\dfrac{1}{n}\mathrm{trace}(A)\mathrm{I}_n$$ in which $\mathrm{trace}(A)$ means the trace of $A$ and $\mathrm{I}_n$ is the identity. Then, obviously, the trace of $A-\dfrac{1}{n}\mathrm{trace}(A)\mathrm{I}_n$ is $0$, and thus it is a traceless matrix. Therefore, $A$ is a sum of a scalar matrix and traceless matrices.

However, when the characteristic of $F$ is not $0$, I do not know anything about such as decomposition. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $A-cI_n$ is traceless iff $\operatorname{trace}(A)=cn$. How does the solubility of that equation depend on the field characteristic?

Comment: Over the field of two elements $\mathbb{F}_2$ there are exactly two scalar matrices of second order: $0$, $I$. Therefore the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ cannot be represented as you want.

Comment: This decomposition is common in _Continuum Mechanics_ where it is called the Isotropic-Deviatoric decomposition. Perhaps a textbook in that subject will have a chapter or appendix that addresses your specific question.

Comment: Thank you very much.